# Почему в СО Ubuntu звук лагает от операций с ССД ФС монтированной с флагом sync?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fstream, ssd, pulseaudio

Почему в ОС Ubuntu звук лагает от операций с ССД ФС монтированной с флагом sync?
Кроме того в браузере Firefox 66 лагает прокрутка, закешированных страниц. При этом приоритет PulseAudio стоит самый высокий, и процессор 2 ядра, загружен не более 60% на ядро. 
При этом лагают не все прогарммы, а их многие. Напишите причину затратности синхронизации ФС
Алгоритм. Поставить флажок занято, ожидать, освободить флажок, следующая операция.
Это же не затратно